# Prevent page refresh when Chrome DevTools opens

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Not sure whether it's a bug or feature, but it brings inconvinience to me.

Every time I launch Chrome DevTools by pressing F12 on 95% websites I have to wait for page to refresh which is initiated by browser. I noticed, that this issue might be caused by CPU manufacturer of my working machine, e.g.:

AMD A-10 laptop, 6 Gb of RAM: **refresh**
Intel i7-920, 12 Gb of RAM: **no refresh**
Intel i7-4770 desktop, 24 Gb of RAM: **no refresh**
AMD Ryzen 5 3600, 16 Gb of RAM: **refresh**

If I close DevTools and then open it again without closing current tab there is no refresh.

Does anyone have the same issue? Is there any way to fix it except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273767/how-can-i-block-page-autorefresh-in-google-chrome)?

Comment: Can you show us your network tab (with 'Preserve log' enabled)? Take special note of the 'Initiator'.

Comment: @Ahmad Somehow I can't reach same bug right now on AMD-powered desktop... 5 mins. ago Chrome updated to ver. 80.0, maybe that's the reason. Anyway, if I will suffer it again I'll check console.

Comment: Devtools should never do this. Sounds like a bug or an extension you've installed, disable them on chrome://extensions page. Could be also a utility in your OS that listens to F12 hotkey and sends Ctrl-R in addition so try invoking devtools via right-click menu -> inspect.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ctrl+Shift+C caused page reload as well, also I got same problem on 2 different PC, so your suggestion about utility doesn't fit. I assume this caused by Chrome's RAM overuse.

Comment: 1) A utility can intercept all devtools hotkeys. 2) My comment contained other ideas as well.

Comment: @wOxxOm I deeply appreciate your intension to help me, and I read your comment from start to end. Some extentions really might cause such behavior. Even though I doubt it, I will try some combinations like turning off ADBlock or Vue DevTools. Thank you.

Comment: There was a [similar bug](https://crbug.com/1043888) which will be fixed in the next update of Chrome 80.

Comment: @Ahmad Got the issue once again, "Initiator" is unknown. Before document is forced to reload I can see a request sent to "root.s-i-z.com" with base64-like GET param. DevTools console is forced to be cleared 1000 times, lots of "img" output there before "console.clear()" attempt.

Comment: Try switching off JavaScript. If it still reloads, then it must be Chrome. If it doesn't, it's probably a keypress event firing as @wOxxOmm suggested.

Comment: Same thing happens to me even if I do not have any AdBlock extensions installed. @wOxxOm it also happens when I right click and inspect on any web page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPD: Now I'm sure the reason of such behavior is "AdBlock Plus" Chrome Extension (ID: cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb).

I think the refresh started to happen after the extension's update. When I open DevTools in Chrome Incognito mode AdBlock is disabled and I get no refresh, also there's no refresh on another PC I use with no AdBlock.

Comment: I do not have any AdBlocker extension installed, still I face the same exact issue. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Srk95 Try to launch Chrome in Incognito mode and turn every extension off. Eventually, you will find the one that reloads page. Lack of RAM might cause this as well, I think.

Comment: Disabling my AdBlocker solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some extensions cause page refreshes, such as "Awesome Color Picker"